# Can't change the background-color to transparent on pagination link

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using dir-pagination found [here.](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination)

This utilizes *bootstrap styling*. I can change the rest of the styles for the pagination controls, but I can't force the `hover` effect to have no color.

I can ensure that it has a color, by specifying one, but if I try to **override** it in a way that will force it to not have a color such as transparent, it defaults to the white color. My specificity is exactly the same as in the bootstrap css... but even if I remove the style in the bootstrap css is still defaults to white.

Been researching this for hours.

EDIT: See the following plunkr for an example of my problem.
http://plnkr.co/edit/2OvXNgX81NspuO9g356J?p=preview

Comment: Try to set `rgba(0,0,0,0)` or `rgba(0,0,0,.01)` also, just to be sure, maybe you have a white element behind, so you set transparent on hover successfully, but you see another element behind this transparent layer? Set `rgba(255,0,0,.5)` and we'll see.

Comment: Well, I already tried the first two things you listed... it sets it as full bright white. What are you expecting to see from the second thing?

Comment: And what about the last one?

Comment: The resulting flattened rgb is 255, 128, 128. So it's a pink.

Comment: So it means that you have another element behind an element you're hovering and it's white. Use code inspector (like F12 in Chrome) and determinate it

Comment: I stepped up the html hierarchy. The body was white, but I already tried changing that long ago to no effect. Nothing seems to be contributing a background color anymore, but I still get that white. I am checking with chrome inspector on the compiled css.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. What do you expect to see if not `body`? A hole in a browser window?

Comment: I expect to see the green of the element below.

Comment: Can you provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And please use "@nick_name" like "@Cheslab" for example so I can see a notification when you post an answer

Comment: @Cheslab Please see this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/2OvXNgX81NspuO9g356J?p=preview

Comment: I can't see your problem. What do you want to see when hovering page numbers? There is no green elements below it. Do you understand the meaning of word _transparent_? If you want page numbers to be green on hover so don't change their color at all, because they are already green. If you want them to become transparent - be ready to see through them.

Comment: @Cheslab I understand transparent perfectly well. I falsely thought I had my elements overlaying each other to create a multiplying effect... but I didn't have that set up yet. I put this in an answer.

Comment: That explains everything... let me make another cup of coffee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized my mistake and I feel foolish. I was making the assumption I had another element below with the color I wanted, and I was simply changing the color of an overlay element.

Turns out I didn't have that other element below, and so it really was just pulling the white of the monitor. I was a little clouded by the complexity of my current project that I didn't see it like I did with the simplicity of the plunkr example I made.

Answer (score 1):

**twilliams** Hi there.

Is this what you are trying to do?

Add this to your css.

`.pagination li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255,128,128,.5);
}`

This will change the pagination background transparent color when each one is hovered.

Have a look at this **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JGS20ugkgPqQRjyGyElV?p=preview)**.

Comment: Hi AngularJR. That unfortunately is not what I was looking for. But thanks for finding that plunker, I was having trouble creating one myself. Please see this edited plunker to see my problem. You can force one of those buttons to be hover state, and inspect it and there's no white background anywhere that I can tell. http://plnkr.co/edit/2OvXNgX81NspuO9g356J?p=preview

Comment: Hi, not understanding the problem here. Can you try to explain a little more please. White background ??

Comment: Is the problem this? Look at the last line in your css and in the rgba() the last value should be 0.X . Like this rgba(0,0,0, **0.1**);.